# How can I sort alphanumeric strings in Sails?

Tags: sails.js

I have a list of table names, which are out of order. How can I get them in the correct logical order?

Raw data:

```
Item 5
Item 1
Item New
Item 2
Item 3
Item 1534
Item 6
```

After doing `Item.find().sort('itemName ASC')`

```
Item 1
Item 1534
Item 2
Item 3
Item 5
Item 6
Item New
```

Expected order:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 5
Item 6
Item 1534
Item New
```

How can I achieve the expected result ?

Comment: What database and what have you tried so far? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need **Natural sort**

Here is article about that:
http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html

Some theory: http://web.archive.org/web/20130826203933/http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1671288

And Stack questions you may find interesting:

1. [Underscore.js sort an array of objects alphanumerically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25101038/underscore-js-sort-an-array-of-objects-alphanumerically)
2. [Javascript : natural sort of alphanumerical strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings)

Comment: Interesting reading, I ended up doing something similar with JavaScript